# How much frost is too much frost for a fiddle leaf fig

Tags: tropical, frost

Recently, I received a fiddle leaf fig from someone who could not care for it. They had been keeping it outside (Zone 6A, formerly 5B) for the summer and, unfortunately, I didn’t get to it before three or four days of (what I think of as) mild frost 25F-32F (-4-0C).

I brought it home and it is now indoors, but there is clearly some damage to the leaves at least. A bunch have turned brown, though most of the ones at the bottom remain fully green. Some of the leaves toward the top have some slight green speckling on mostly brown leaves.

I’ve never had a fiddle leaf fig, let alone had to save one from frost damage, so wondering if anyone else reading has dealt with this problem for a fiddle leaf fig or another tropical plant. Is there anything specific I can do other than bringing it inside and hoping for the best?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough plant once established and buds readily from old wood.  Just wait and see.  You will have to be patient as most tropical plants do not grow a lot in the northern hemisphere at this time of the year due to the reduced light levels.

The brown leaves are dead and can be removed once they dry up.  If the stems are a bit bare just cut it back to a green leaf and wait for new growth.

Fertilize at 1/4 strength once a month in the spring and you are good to go.